# click event not fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am trying to fire click event on BackBone, but dont get any event, 
looks like I do have the selector is correct but still cant get it working, thnx for help!
My code is:

```
  events: {
      "click #search_button": "doSearch"
    },
    doSearch: function (event) {
      // Button clicked, you can access the element that was clicked with event.currentTarget
      alert("Search for " + $("#search_input").val());
    }
  });

  var search_view = new SearchView({el: $("#search_container")});
  search_view.delegateEvents();
```

template:

```
<div class="jumbotron" id="search_template">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for..." id="search_input">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" id="search_button" type="button">Go!</button>
  </span>
        </div><!-- /input-group -->
      </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
    </div><!-- /.row -->

  </div>
</div>
<div id="search_container"></div>
```

Comment: Your doSearch method is fired because you can get target element through event.currentTarget. Why do you decided that your event don't work?

Comment: There is no `search_container` element in your code for the Backbone view to be bound to.

Comment: forgot to past it to post... now I update it...

Comment: @AlexanderShlenchack because I debug it and the debuger not going to this function...

Comment: Events are delegated through the view's `el` but your `#search_button` is not inside `#search_container`.

Comment: @muistooshort please make it as comment this is the correct answer!